# Symfony 2: How to avoid assets being deleted? (on windows)

Tags: php, symfony, assets

Sometimes the command to publish the assets deletes all of them (directly form the bundle!!) instead of copying/symlinking them.

I tried both of these commands:

```
php app/console assets:install web

php app/console assets:install --symlink web
```

Both work sometimes, but some other times they ruin everything and I have to go back to the last changeset (god bless mercurial). They even delete the assets from the framework and the demos.

Is this a bug, or am I using the wrong command?

I think there's a bug around the piece of code that is supposed to clear the web/bundles directory. Instead, it is deleting everything (randomly) directly from the bundles, eg: MyBundle/Resources/public

Comment: Which version of windows are you using? Symlinking won't work on XP, it's only available since Vista.

Comment: windows 7. It worked sometimes. Some other times it deleted everything, directly from the bundle

Comment: Which version of Symfony 2? Are you using the latest RC?

Comment: I'm using the RC3. I have been finding lots of bugs on windows, they don't seem to care.

Comment: Hmm. I'm using RC3 on Windows 7 too, but haven't been experiencing this issue. I'll take a look and see where it could be going wrong for you.

Comment: I'm having the same problem here, any news?

Comment: I have the same problem!

Answer (score 0):

Try starting on the debug mode, that way you won't need to use assetic:install again and again.
app/console commands gives how to start debug assetic mode

```
app/console assetic:dump
```